# How to determine whether a string is a hash

Tags: java, cryptography

I have to implement a Java method, which will determine, if a input string is a hash (generated by a machine) or a plain-text (written by a human).

Example:

```
isThisEncrypted("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"); // returns true
isThisEncrypted("some normal human text"); // returns false
```

I thought about using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (jsc.goodnessfit.KolmogorovTest), which will check, if a characters in a string are from normal distribution, but I have learned, that checking only one, short string might not be conclusive.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem in Java (preferably using a existing library)?

Comment: This whole thing seems dangerous, an algorthim could just by chance generate a string that looks human

Comment: Do you control the hashing function, will the user input always have several words?

Comment: I know, that this will not be an oracle, ~80% of accuracy will be enough.

Comment: well, depending on the scenario and the algo, you could test against the length of hash(if the algo produces constant length output), you could also check for spaces. However this is not a full proof strategy, you will need to find a work around, the right way is to compare the hash against the hash of stored plaintext. This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648929/check-if-string-is-a-hash is different to your question but might prove helpful.

Comment: hashing and encryption are two different things. Which one are you generating?

Comment: Yes, I control the encrypting method, and no, human input can be random (one word, several words, oneWordCreatedFromSeveral etc.)

Comment: If you control the encrypting then why not put a flag on the front, so encript as usual and then just put ENC or similar on the front?. Why are user inputs and encrypyted inputs coming in the same route anyway?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - my encryption method is using the Blowfish algortihm, this method has to determin, if string comes from this method or form user.

Comment: @Richard - I can't do that, because after my encryption method returns encrypted string this string could be used by another (third party) plugins and methods. After that it could come back to my module and then I have to determin, if given string was previously encrypted by me or not.

Comment: @Richard - it comes from the same route, because I am developing a KNIME node, and it has to have only one input port (with one table, containgn encrypted and not encrypted data).

Comment: @varun - there is no stored plaintext, it is delivered to this method on the fly.

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why exactly are you trying to determine this? Perhaps there is a better way to solve the background problem.

Comment: @Duncan - I'm writing a KNIME node, which will encrypt and decrypt data (which will be provided by another nodes). There must be only one window, in which there must be only two columns. In first one, there is an input data, and user must drag-and-drop it to te second one. Data from this column will be encrypted or decrypted. I need this method to prompt user, which data from first column was previously encrypted by my node and which wasn't. This will help the user to choose only this data, which he really wants to put in secon column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stated that you only want an approximate solution (80% accuracy), that classes of the form AClassName are likely (note capitalisation) and the given sample of encrypted text has no capitals in it. So

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] tests=new String[5];

        tests[0]="MyClass";
        tests[1]="Short";
        tests[2]="thsrjtyzfgnmytkzrhjstk";
        tests[3]="tatm";
        tests[4]="The result is good";

        for(int i=0;i<tests.length;i++){
            System.out.println(tests[i]+ "- Encrypted:" + isProbablyEncrypted(tests[i]));
        }


    }

    public static boolean isProbablyEncrypted(String in){
        int noOfWords= countOccurrences(in, ' ') + countCaps(in);
        if (noOfWords==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            double averageWordLength=(double)(in.length())/(noOfWords+1);

            if (averageWordLength>15){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int countOccurrences(String haystack, char needle)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < haystack.length(); i++)
        {
            if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle)
            {
                 count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int countCaps(String in){
        int caps=0;
        for (int i=0; i<in.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(in.charAt(i)))caps++;
        }
        return caps;
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution; no, does it give >80% accuracy; yes

Comment: The only thing this fails on is one word sentences that aren't classes

Comment: I'm assuming you do a later check for encryption thats long and expensive?

Comment: If encryted text can contain capitals at 50% probability then very short average word scores would also imply encryption

Answer (score 3):

From your comments:

> human input can be random
>
> this method has to determin, if string comes from this method or form
>   user

Then there's no way to solve your problem having just the String. You need extra information.

If you're expecting Blowfish to return a String in a given format, then you're wrong. Modern encryption algorithms target high entropy, which means they have to look and feel like random.

Comment: I do not expect Blowfish to return string in a given format. I expect that it will be random. By saying, that human input can be random I meant, that it can be one word, several words, orOneWordCreatedFromSeveralWords. This method has to tell me, if input is clearly a random string (e.g. "edgyewfduysfd") or something "humanish" (e.g. "BusinessLogicCoreClass"). So that's why my first gues was to check normal distribution of input string.

Comment: And I will say this again: this method doesn't have to be an oracle, 80% of accuracy will be enaugh :) (its result will be only a hint)

Comment: @user2265495 80% accuracy; check for word length, assuming the algorithm even puts spaces in then they'll occure 1 in 27 times, whereas I'd expect english language to be 1 in 5 or 6. One word: less that 20% of time probably, many words without spaces: how often does that happen

Comment: @Richard - unfortunatly, many words without spaces could happen frequently in this case, because this KNIME node will encrypt and decrypt class names (among other stuff). So strings like "BusinessLogicCoreClass" will be quite normal input for this node.

Comment: @user2265495: *"This method has to tell me, if input is clearly a random string (e.g. "edgyewfduysfd") or something "humanish" (e.g. "BusinessLogicCoreClass")"* Then you have to calculate its entropy, but again, my point is that a human can provide a string which is random enough to fool this method (the shorter the string, the more probable the fooling). Probably Richard's answer is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You split your input into words and check them against a dictionary ( [checking words in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032064/checking-words-in-a-dictionary) ) .

From now on everything depends on your implementation. IMO, if half the words match with the dictionary, then your method should return false.